# Postgresql: read uncommitted data in the same transaction

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, transactions

the problem is using PostgreSQL via JDBC:

1. start transaction (implicit)
2. insert a row
3. select that involve the row you just insert
4. other
5. commit

and seems results of select don't consider the insert.

the actual need is that in a first insert i insert in a table the current time-stamp (i want to use the db one, not the date time of the time server!!) and i need that value in another insert in another table in the same transaction.

Comment: The select will most certainly "consider" changes made in the same transaction. Please show us some *reproducible* code that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: It's really basic: create a preparedstatement and do an insert with a timestamp, then right next before the commit do a flat select column from table1 and the command next() of resultset will raise false...no rows in the table until the commit....

Comment: There **must** be something you are not telling us. What you describe is the most basic handling of transaction and it definitely works in Postgres that way. Please post the full Java code.

Comment: Sorry, you are right, actually was an error (a stupid one as often happens) in the parameter settings...thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the `select` doesn't see the rows produced by the `insert`, then the code you're running doesn't do what you think. The only ways this can really happen are:

- Each statement is run in autocommit mode, the `insert` fails, and you swallow the exception.
- Each statement is being run in its own *new* transaction, which remains open and uncommitted - so the `insert` is in a different not-yet-committed tx to the `select`.
- The `insert` or `select` don't do what you think they do.

To tell you more, it would be necessary to *see the code* - both the client code, and the generated SQL.